# Custom view on JavaFX's ComboBox

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, controls, custom-component

I'm currently trying to change the default ComboBox class from JavaFX to display a TextField and a Button on the top of the ListView.

The TextField would be used to filter the contents of the ListView and the button would be used to clear the ComboBox contents (basically the button would call `getSelectionModel().clearSelection();`).

However, I can't find anywhere a sample to use a custom view to display the scenario I've posted above.

I've tried to subclass the ComboBox class, but I cannot get the view to show. I'm using a VBox to include the controls. I haven't got around to add the Button yet. Here's the code:

```
public class ComboBoxFilter<T> extends ComboBox<T> {
    protected TextField filterField;

    @Override protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        initFilter();

        return(new ComboBoxFilterViewSkin<T>(this));
    }

    protected void initFilter() {       
        filterField = new TextField();
    }

    class ComboBoxFilterViewSkin<T> extends ComboBoxListViewSkin<T> {
        protected VBox filterPane;

        public ComboBoxFilterViewSkin(ComboBox<T> comboBox) {
            super(comboBox);
        }

        @Override public Node getPopupContent() {
            filterPane = new VBox();
            filterPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            filterPane.setSpacing(8);

            filterPane.getChildren().addAll(filterField, getListView());
            filterPane.setMinWidth(getListView().getWidth());
            filterPane.setMinHeight(getListView().getHeight() + filterField.getHeight());

            return(filterPane);
        }       
    }   
}
```

I'm aware that there is a solution that sets the ComboBox into editable and filters the ListView, but that solution does not work for my needs.

Can anyone provide an insight on how should I proceed to implement the scenario I need? It does not have to be on top of the class presented above. I'm willing to go with another approach.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems overkill; I don't think you need a custom skin at all here. Just set a custom `buttonCell` on the `ComboBox` to display a text field and a button.

Comment: Thanks, James_D, but how can I make that happen, since I only want them displayed when the ListView is visible?

Comment: Ah, OK, I misunderstood "on top of the list view"... Maybe this is the better approach for what you want.

Comment: Any solution for this? I have the exact same predicament. When opening the combobox I would like it to show a text field which will be used to filter the list. When the combobox is closed, but has a selected value I would like to add a X(close) button right aside the arrow down button.